# Callback function for form validation in config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, email-validation

I'm trying to do an email validation whereby the domain of the email would be `@abc123.com`. I've separated my form validation rules into another file in the `application/config` folder called `form_validation.php`. One of my rules consists of a `callback_email_check`.

Where should I put the function? In the main controller or together with the `form_validation.php` file where all my form validation rules are? I've tried putting at both options but at where I display my error message I'm getting an output saying `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Email.(email_check)`.

```
function email_check($email)
{
    if( strpos($email, '@abc123.com') !== FALSE ) return TRUE;

    $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please use abc123 email only.');

    return FALSE;
}
```

form_validation.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Form Validation Rules */

$config = array(
    'login' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'user_id',
                    'label' => 'User ID',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
    ),
    'sign_up' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'user_id',
                    'label' => 'User ID',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'label' => 'Name',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'department',
                    'label' => 'Department',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'cfm_password',
                    'label' => 'Re-type Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[password]'
            )
    ),
    'edit_profile' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'new_password',
                    'label' => 'New Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'retype_password',
                    'label' => 'Re-type Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[new_password]'
            )
    ),
    'forgot_password' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'user_id',
                    'label' => 'User ID',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check'
            )
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: Callback functions are placed within the same controllers  from which they are called in form validation.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi I've tried that, but it returns the same error.

Comment: will you post your set_rule part also

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi Then that would ignore the error, I'm trying to set a rule to make sure the user only uses '@abc123.com' as the domain.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi Tried it already, like I said it ignores the check for the domain since it'll always be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your function email_check, the set_message is not correct it should be the same name as the function.

Change this

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please use abc123 email only.');
```

To

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Please use abc123 email only.');
```

Call backs http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: I assumed it was the name, which was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Not working get same error any suggestion @Wolfgang1983

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem and this is how i resolved it...

You can put email_check function in same controller. In case you are not getting the error message in callback then pass $this in your run()

if ($this->form_validation->run($this)) { ...}

and associating a Controller Method with a Rule Group -

$config = array(
    'controller/method' => array(...));

view link for more : [associating a Controller Method with a Rule Group][1]

cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your config:

```
array(
      'field' => 'email',
      'label' => 'Email',
      'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check',
       **'errors' => array('email_check' => 'Your Error Message')**
),
```