# Form Validation Saved Callback

Tags: codeigniter

application/controllers/UserController.php

```
public function reg_form() 
{   
   $input_data_array = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));         
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','first_name','required|trim|alpha|callback_username_check'); 
   $this->form_validation->set_data($input_data_array);         
   if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE)      
   {
    $result = array('status' => 404,'message' => $this->form_validation->error_array());
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));        
   }
   else 
   {
    $result = array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Executed Succesfully','data'=>$input_data_array);
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));        
   }    
}
```

application/config/form_validation.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config = array(
    'signup' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'first_name',
                    'label' => 'first_name',
                    'rules' => 'callback_username_check'                    
            )    
));

public function username_check($str)
{
        if ($str == 'admin')
        {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "admin"');
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
                return TRUE;
        }
}
```

If is Remove 'public' access specifier written before username_check function, I get,

> {"status":404,"message":{"first_name":"Unable to access an error
>   message corresponding to your field name
>   first_name.(username_check)"}}

else I am getting,

> syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file

I already referred to the solutions given on [Callback function for form validation in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835166/callback-function-for-form-validation-in-config-file) but it did not work out.

In brief, I am having the errors when I am placing callback function definition in the form_validation.php  (for reuse) and not in the Controller file. 
Please help.

Comment: your callback method should be in your UserController.php

Comment: @pradeep I know that, its mentioned in doc. But then I need to copy that callback function in all the Controller files where I want to use it. It would be resulting into redundancy. Is there a way out to define in the form_validation.php file where I am writing my saved validation. Someone else was getting the same error like me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835166/callback-function-for-form-validation-in-config-file . But the solution that worked for him is not working for me.

Comment: you can use other alternative like callable within your  controller or in form_validation

Comment: @pradeep Thank You It worked

Comment: @pradeep Callable solved the issue of writing the custom validation in form_validation file as I wrote in the solution below, but again the issue of reusability persist, as I need to write that same callable function again when required in another validation rules group. Any solution for it?

Comment: that is why defining callbacks in controller can be  somewhat more reusable. if defines in controller you can just call same callback from different method

Answer (score 0):

Callable Worked out for me,
So now my Controller function and form_validation.php file is as follows:

application/controllers/UserController.php

```
public function reg_form() 
{   
   $input_data_array = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));   

   $this->form_validation->set_data($input_data_array);         
   if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE)      
   {
    $result = array('status' => 404,'message' => $this->form_validation->error_array());
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));        
   }
   else 
   {
    $result = array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Executed Succesfully','data'=>$input_data_array);
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));        
   }    
}
```

application/config/form_validation.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config = array(
    'signup' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'first_name',
                    'label' => 'first_name',
                    'rules' => array(
                        'required',
                         array(
                                'username_callable',
                                function($str)
                                {
                                    if($str == 'admin')
                                    {
                                        return TRUE;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        return FALSE;
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                ),
                'errors' => array(
                    'username_callable' => 'Invalid Name',
            )  
)));
```